# How to upload an image by calling a REST API in PHP?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, curl

I am doing project in laravel. After form submit I want to move uploaded file to the rest api folder.
For that I called curl function in my controller method.

**controller.php**

```
{
    if($request->hasFile('filefield')){

        $file = $request->file('filefield');

        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
        $mimeType =  finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);

        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $method = 'POST';
        $url = 'engagev1be.taarago.in/superadmin';
        $data = array('file' => new \CurlFile($file,$mimeType,$filename), 'oldpath' =>$oldpath,'id'=>$id);
        $result = $this->CallAPI($method,$url,$data);
     }
}
```

and **CallAPI function** is like,

```
public function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

and at rest api my **Route.php** is,

```
Route::post('superadmin', 'SuperadminController@uploadimg');
```

and **SuperadminController@uploadimg** is,

```
public function uploadimg(Request $request){

    $file = $request->file;
    $oldpath = $request->oldpath;
    $id = $request->id;
    $editProvider = Provider::findOrFail($id);
    if($file){
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = str_replace('%', ' ', $filename);

        $newpath = 'images/provider_images/'.$id;
        if (!file_exists($newpath)) {
            File::makeDirectory($newpath, 0777, true, true);
            $newpath = 'images/provider_images/'.$id;
        }
        $success = move_uploaded_file($oldpath,$newpath.'/'.$filename);
        $editProvider->profile_pic = $newpath.'/'.$filename;
        $editProvider->update();
        return $success ;
    }
}
```

Here in this case $success returns none as in file is not getting uploaded.
I am getting what to do, when I do,

```
dd($request->all());
```

then it ruturns result as,

```
array:3 [▼
  "oldpath" => "/tmp/phpmyoWT4"
  "id" => "61"
  "file" => UploadedFile {#30 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "images.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -size: 5126
    -error: 0
  }
]
```

Which means, file returned successfully to the rest api but not getting uploaded.